# estimate for derivative of convolution

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty))$ be a function such that $$u(x+z,t)-u(x,t)\leq c\left(1 + \frac 1 c\right)z\tag{$*$}$$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb R$ and almost all $x,z\in\mathbb R$, $t,z>0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $\eta_\varepsilon\in C_C^\infty$ be the standard mollifier in the $x$ and $t$ variables with properties

1. $\eta_\varepsilon\geq 0$
2. $\operatorname{supp}\eta_\varepsilon\subset B_\varepsilon(0)$
3. $\int_0^\infty\int_{\mathbb R} \eta_\varepsilon(x,t) dx dt = 1$

Then we have $$\frac{d}{dx}(\eta_\varepsilon*u)(x,t) \leq c'\left(1+\frac 1 t\right)$$ for all $t\geq 2\varepsilon$ for some constant $c'$ independent of $\varepsilon$.

I tried showing this, but I am not sure about my proof because it does not make use of $\varepsilon$, except in the mollifier $\eta_\varepsilon$:

From $(*)$ we have after dividing by $z$ and using $z\to 0$ that $$\frac{d}{dx}u(x,t)\leq c\left(1+\frac 1 t\right)$$ 
Now by partial integration we have $$\eta_\varepsilon*u_x(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb R} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y) u_x(y)dy = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\eta_\varepsilon*u\right)$$

and since $\eta_\varepsilon\geq 0$ we thus have the estimate \begin{align*}
 \frac{d}{dx}(\eta_\varepsilon*u) & = \int_{\mathbb R} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)u_x(y)dy \\
& \leq c\left(1+\frac 1 t\right)\int_{\mathbb R} \eta_\varepsilon(z)dz \\
& \leq c\left(1+\frac 1 t\right)\int_0^\infty\int_{\mathbb R} \eta_\varepsilon dz dt \\
& = c\left(1+\frac 1 t \right)
\end{align*}

Is this proof okay or otherwise can anyone help me correct it? Thanks!

Comment: In your very first step (where you use $(\ast)$), you are using (**assuming**) that $u(\cdot, t)$ is differentiable. This does not have to be the case.

Comment: oh, yes, you are right! Do you have an idea on how to avoid using/assuming differentiability?

Comment: Do I not get the differentiability from ($*$)? We know that for $t\geq 2\varepsilon$ $c\left(1+\frac 1 t\right)$ is bounded and hence the limit in ($*$) is (maybe large but) finite and hence $u_x(x,t)$ exists at time $t$?

Comment: Consider for example $u(x,t)=|x|$ (this is not in $L^\infty$, but ignore thy for the moment). This satisfies $(\ast)$, but is not differentiable in $0$.

Comment: okay, I see your point.